# How to get aws instance metadata remotely using CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, metadata

I am very new to AWS. I have a **Windows Server** EC2 instance. I installed AWS CLI on my **laptop**. Then I opened a CMD window, typed in "aws configure", put in the access key credentials, and was able to connect to the EC2.

From here, how do I get the http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data working? How do I retrieve some meta data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**On your Laptop**

On your local machine you only can use the cli to retrieve metadata about your instance. Simply use this aws cli command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id <your-ec_instance_id e.g. i-ab12345> --attribute instanceType --region <your_region e.g. eu-west-1>
```

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-attribute.html

**On your EC2-Instance only:**
On your instance you can use the cli (like above) and the following:

PowerShell >3.0:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Or you can install "curl for windows" and run:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type
```

Answer (score 5):

When running on an EC2 instance, you can query the metadata service, like so:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

You can also use:

```
curl http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

From *outside* the EC2 instance, you can use the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), like so:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
    --instance-ids i-01234567890123456
    --query "Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress"
    --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data from AWS cli on your **laptop**

Use the `ec2  describe-instances` command instead for getting instance details

More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)